# Simplify a longer unrolled loop expression with constexpr or template metaprogramming

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming

It looks like I have a longer expression (unrolled loop) such as the code below several times in a piece of software which bloats it up by several thousand lines.

Since `poly` takes template arguments for performance (**the second argument corresponds to the loops z value**), I wonder whether one can simplify the code below by template meta programming and building by recursion something like a loop. The syntax of the expression seems to be for each `x` = `bx (a + b + c * by * bz) + ..`

I guess, it would be easier if `poly` wouldn't be a template function, but taking function parameters.

```
void calc(float mat[3][3][3], float fS, float fT, float fU)
{
    const float bs20_u = poly<2, 0>(fU);
    const float bs21_u = poly<2, 1>(fU);
    const float bs22_u = poly<2, 2>(fU);

    const float bs20_s = poly<2, 0>(fS);
    const float bs21_s = poly<2, 1>(fS);
    const float bs22_s = poly<2, 2>(fS);

    const float bs20_t = poly<2, 0>(fT);
    const float bs21_t = poly<2, 1>(fT);
    const float bs22_t = poly<2, 2>(fT);

    float result = 
       ((mat[0][0][0] * bs20_u + mat[0][0][1] * bs21_u + mat[0][0][2] * bs22_u) * bs20_t
      + (mat[0][1][0] * bs20_u + mat[0][1][1] * bs21_u + mat[0][1][2] * bs22_u) * bs21_t
      + (mat[0][2][0] * bs20_u + mat[0][2][1] * bs21_u + mat[0][2][2] * bs22_u) * bs22_t)
      * bs20_s
      +
       ((mat[1][0][0] * bs20_u + mat[1][0][1] * bs21_u + mat[1][0][2] * bs22_u) * bs20_t
      + (mat[1][1][0] * bs20_u + mat[1][1][1] * bs21_u + mat[1][1][2] * bs22_u) * bs21_t
      + (mat[1][2][0] * bs20_u + mat[1][2][1] * bs21_u + mat[1][2][2] * bs22_u) * bs22_t)
      * bs21_s
      +
       ((mat[2][0][0] * bs20_u + mat[2][0][1] * bs21_u + mat[2][0][2] * bs22_u) * bs20_t
      + (mat[2][1][0] * bs20_u + mat[2][1][1] * bs21_u + mat[2][1][2] * bs22_u) * bs21_t
      + (mat[2][2][0] * bs20_u + mat[2][2][1] * bs21_u + mat[2][2][2] * bs22_u) * bs22_t)
      * bs22_s;
}
```

Comment: You may start with partially specializing `poly`, as its first argument is always `2` in your case.

Comment: @iehrlich but you cannot partially specialize a function template...

Comment: I noticed that it would be simpler if a function could be specialized

Comment: @Quentin but you can write `template<int J>
float poly2(float in)
{
    return poly<2, J>();
}`

Comment: @iehrlich that's overloading -- close enough :)

Comment: @Quentin not exactly overloading (the signature is different), but not the partial specialization either. In fact, it's merely a de-templatization, if you'll allow me :)

Comment: @dgrat please clarify two things: (1) are you focused on constexpr/templates within this ticket, or just looking for refactoring opportunities in general? (2) is your complete code available somewhere?

Comment: @iehrlich
I was looking for a method to make the code more compact by usage of templates, mainly because poly<> is already constexpr and I think it is bad style unroll a complete matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<std::size_t...Is>
auto index_over(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
  return [](auto&& f)->decltype(auto){
    return decltype(f)(f)( std::integral_constant< std::size_t, Is >{}... );
  };
}
template<std::size_t N>
auto index_upto(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N> ={}) {
  return index_over( std::make_index_sequence<N>{} );
}
inline float sum() { return 0.0f; }
template<class...Args>
float sum( float a, Args... args ) {
  return a + sum(args...);
}
```

I think those should do it.

```
auto Z_f = [&](auto X, auto Y)->float {
  return index_upto<2>()( [&](auto...Zs)->float{
    return sum((poly<2,Zs>(fU) * mat[X][Y][Zs])...);
  });
};
auto Y_f = [&](auto X)->float {
  return index_upto<2>()( [&](auto...Ys)->float{
    return sum( (poly<2,Ys>(fT) * Z_f(X, Ys))... );
  });
};
auto X_f = [&]()->float {
  return index_upto<2>()( [&](auto...Xs)->float{
    return sum( (poly<2,Xs>(fS) * Y_f(Xs))... );
  });
};

float val = X_f();
```

not sure if this is any briefer, but maybe with some more work we can refactor the `X_f`, `Y_f` and `Z_f` into one function.

clang is capable of optimizing this with constant input into a constant value.

This uses some C++14 constructs (`index_sequence` and `make_index_sequence`) which can be reimplemented easily in C++11.

I use `auto` arguments in order to make template lambdas, again C++14.  Doing this in C++11 requires you to manually write said lambdas, which is a pain.

`sum` can be written as `(0.f + ... + args)` in C++17.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0599ae0731731f78) showing it run.

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/xSK3R7) showing it compiles down to a constant.

If you don't need to preserve the exact order of operations, and are willing to have more multilpications, we could generate a case where we get all 3 of the Xs, Ys and Zs, and then call a target with a compile-time constant and add up the results.

```
auto contribution = [&](auto X, auto Y, auto Z) {
  return mat[X][Y][Z] * poly<2,X>(fS) * poly2<2,Y>(fT) * poly2<2,Z>(fU);
};
```

but I have issues doing this in one line, as you end up with 3 active packs that you want to expand separately.

```
auto summer_1d = [](auto...Vals)->decltype(auto){
  return sum(Vals...);
};
template<std::size_t X_max, std::size_t Y_max, std::size_t Z_max, class Sum = decltype(summer_1d)>
auto sumup_3d(Sum sum = summer_1d) {
  return [](auto&& f)->decltype(auto) {
    auto Z_part = [&](auto X, auto Y)->decltype(auto) {
      return index_upto<Z_max>()([&](auto...Zs)->decltype(auto){
        return sum( f(X,Y,Zs)... );
      });
    };
    auto Y_part = [&](auto X)->decltype(auto) {
      return index_upto<Y_max>()([&](auto...Ys)->decltype(auto){
        return sum( Z_part(X, Ys)... );
      });
    };
    return index_upto<X_max>()([&](auto...Xs)->decltype(auto){
      return sum( Y_part(Xs)... );
    });
  };
};

auto val = sumup_3d<3,3,3>()(contribution);
```

or somesuch.

Comment: It looks nice, but there is a c++11 constraint

Comment: @dgrat Notes on how to convert to C++11 added.  The annoying part are the auto lambdas have to be rewritten as template functors.

Comment: I think, I need some time to understand this solution. Looks also like some compilers have problems with it as well. However, I am impressed how complicated templates can become :D I think it is a nice excercise for the mind, though.

Comment: @dgrat replacing `X` with `decltype(X)::value` can help when passing to some C++ compilers.  This solution is going to be really bulky in C++11, which is why I wrote it in C++14.